# Print lists in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to print list in a list using for loop, what i am doing is:

```
k = "/BTC"
for i in range(l):
    if k in dat1["Data"][i]['Label']:
    value = dat1["Data"][i]['Label']
    value1 = dat1["Data"][i]['TradePairId']
    value2 = dat1["Data"][i]['AskPrice']
    value3 = dat1["Data"][i]['BidPrice']
    li1 = [value, value1, value2, value3]
    list = [li1+1 for g in li1]
    print(float(list))
```

on every iteration 'li1' has some values, i want to make a new list that should store the data of 'li1' into an index on every iteration, and then print the whole list in the end. Thanks in advance

Comment: indent you code, cmon its python

Comment: First problem with your code is this line `list = [li1+1 for g in li1]`. You cannot concatenate or add elements to a list like this. Did you mean `[g+1 for g in li1]`?

Comment: Thanks for your positive response, and yeah, Exactly i meant this.

Comment: `for index, row in enumerate(dat1["Data"]):` saves a lot of hassles.

Comment: i've tried this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "store the data of 'li1' into an index". I'm assuming you want a list of lists? You could append the list.

```
k = "/BTC"
result_list = []
for i in range(l):
    if k in dat1["Data"][i]['Label']:
        value = dat1["Data"][i]['Label']
        value1 = dat1["Data"][i]['TradePairId']
        value2 = dat1["Data"][i]['AskPrice']
        value3 = dat1["Data"][i]['BidPrice']
        result_list.append([value, value1, value2, value3])
print(result_list)
```

Comment: If the question is unclear, one shouldn't post a hypothetical answer and instead ask for clarification with a comment.

Comment: I got my answer, Thanks @8324

Comment: Yes, it is the answer!